# reformatting list of lists to another list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
[['X', 'AX'],['X', 'XG'],['XG', 'AXG'],['AX', 'CAX'],['XG', 'XGG'],['AX', 'AXG']]
```

and I want to get

```
[['X', 'AX', 'AXG'], ['X', 'XG', 'AXG'], ['X', 'XG', 'XGG'], ['X', 'AX', 'CAX']]
```

Thus, from `['X', 'AX']` and `['AX', 'CAX']` I want to get `['X', 'AX', 'CAX']`, where the second element of the first list is the first element of the second.

Is there any possibilities to reach it?

Comment: How did you get from the first list to the second ?

Comment: Could you explain how the first list translates into the second?

Comment: from ['X', 'AX'] and ['AX', 'CAX'] get ['X', 'AX', 'CAX'], the second element of the first list is the first element of the second

Comment: It is still unclear, what do you want. If you can't formulate a clear sententce on English, why do you want us to decode your wishes and then implement your task instead you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my overly complex implementation, that goes out of it's way to avoid `range()` which I feel is way over used in what claims to be a high level language, but abuses `reduce()` instead:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

array = [['X', 'AX'], ['X', 'XG'], ['XG', 'AXG'], ['AX', 'CAX'], ['XG', 'XGG'], ['AX', 'AXG']]

def partition(predicate, array):
    return list(takewhile(predicate, array)), dropwhile(predicate, array)

def reducer(accumulated, update):

    for solution in accumulated:
        if solution[-1] == update[0]:
            accumulated.append(solution + update[1:])

    return accumulated

min_length = len(array[0][0])

heads, tails = partition(lambda x: len(x[0]) == min_length, array)

reduction = reduce(reducer, tails, heads)

max_length = len(reduction[-1])

print(list(dropwhile(lambda x: len(x) != max_length, reduction)))
```

OUTPUT

```
[['X', 'XG', 'AXG'], ['X', 'AX', 'CAX'], ['X', 'XG', 'XGG'], ['X', 'AX', 'AXG']]
```

If we change the input to:

```
array = [['X', 'AX'], ['AX', 'CAX'], ['AX', 'AXG'], ['CAX', 'XYZ'], ['CAX', 'ABC'], ['AXG', 'DEF'], ['AXG', 'MNO']]
```

we get the expected output:

```
[['X', 'AX', 'CAX', 'XYZ'], ['X', 'AX', 'CAX', 'ABC'], ['X', 'AX', 'AXG', 'DEF'], ['X', 'AX', 'AXG', 'MNO']]
```

But I suspect there are several potential deviant situations with the input that have not been properly covered in the OP's specification.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I need! I suppose me not to know how to formulate sentences in English, but you understand me

Comment: could you explain me, how this line works? reduction = reduce(reducer, tails, heads). reducer is a function and should take 2 arguments - accumulated, update.

Comment: @uzver, at each iteration, `reducer()` is handed "the solution so far" and "one more element to integrate into that solution".  As I noted, I bent the concept of `reduce()` a bit to make this work to show just one of many ways to think about this problem.  I believe there is likely a better solution but you really need to nail down the rules of this transformation (e.g. What if expansions aren't all of the same length?  Will the data always be in the convenient order to begin with or could it be shuffled?) before settling on the "right" approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just a naive implementation..

You could have simplified it by thinking it as a 1d array of objects(`list()` in our case), and comparing objects starting from 1st to all the next elements.

Just pick 1st element and match it with all the next elements for the condition, then pick 2nd and match it with next elements and so on..

Here our condition for the objects is to have index 1 of first object to be equal to index 1 of second object, so you will implement it like this -

```
l = [['X', 'AX'],['X', 'XG'],['XG', 'AXG'],['AX', 'CAX'],['XG', 'XGG'],['AX', 'AXG']]
l1 = list()
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
        if l[i][1] == l[j][0]:
            l1.append(l[i]+[l[j][1]])

print "l1 = %r"%l1

Output: l1 = [['X', 'AX', 'CAX'], ['X', 'AX', 'AXG'], ['X', 'XG', 'AXG'], ['X', 'XG', 'XGG']]
```

Comment: This doesn't scale.  If I supply input `[['X', 'AX'], ['AX', 'CAX'], ['AX', 'AXG'], ['CAX', 'XYZ'], ['CAX', 'ABC'], ['AXG', 'DEF'], ['AXG', 'MNO']]` I get six groups of three instead of the expected four groups of four.  It may be a simple fix.

Comment: Correct, but the code works as expected output, in your case my code will fail, the code can be refactored depending on the type of expected output, i was just interested in giving an idea of how to get the objects and compare them.